# How can I use Unity indicators -- without Unity?

Tags: indicator

I am trying to get the indicators in the default Unity desktop (battery, bluetooth, etc...) to display in the [awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) window manager. As I understand it, awesome provides a freedesktop.org compliant system tray. For example, `nm-applet` will show up there if I run it.

However, none of the other ordinary indicators will, even if I configure the things in `/etc/xdg/autostart` to start them. For example, if I run `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-bluetooth/indicator-bluetooth-service`, it runs, but I don't see anything in the system tray.

I'm guessing that there's something I need to bridge the gap between the indicator API and the system tray API. Is that correct, and if so, what is it?